# The chat desktop notification guide for Chrome is in need of an update

Tags: feature-request, status-review, chat, help-center

[The Chrome guide to enabling chat desktop notifications](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/help/desktop-notifications) is no longer accurate as Chrome's UI has changed.

Here is my suggested update:

#### Instructions

1. Click on the lock icon in the omnibar.
2. Set notifications to "Allow."
3. Reload the chat window.

[image]

Comment: I submitted a request to have this updated, I will change the tag once it is implemented.